# How to get involved in C standardization process?

Tags: c, standards, c99, c11

Lately I've been getting interest in C standardization. I want to participate in development of C1X. I want to put forward my ideas (irrespective of they being accepted/rejected).

I want to know the procedure. [WG14 documents](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/documents) shows various documents sorted by mailing list. Where can I join one such mailing list? How to submit a proposal? I've seen some proposals, it seems that there is no particular format for initial proposals. At the end of the document, [Status of approved proposals for C9X](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n865.htm) it  gives little information about all 6 stages involved in the process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"If you want further information, or want to participate, please contact your national member body or one of the contact addresses of the WG." -- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/

Although I admire your interest, picture sitting at a staff meeting that lasts for a few years if you want to get a feel for ISO WG efforts.

Answer (score 6):

One thing to remember is that the practice of the C Standard working group is to standardise existing extensions, rather than invent new features out of whole cloth.

So if you have some ideas for features, your first step should be to implement them as an extension for some existing compiler, like gcc.